# Simulating special relativity with a fixed timestep

Tags: special-relativity, simulations

I have a simulation framework that has a fixed time step, a camera, and I can control positions of particles.

Would it be possible to simulate special relativity from the perspective of the camera given the fixed time step, and the fact that some particles accelerate sometimes?

I know that when integrating forces into velocity, I'll need to divide by $1+\frac{v_1\cdot v_2}{c^2}$.

What other modifications would I need to make so the simulation is approximately accurate?

Comment: Simulate it how? Doing length contraction?

Comment: Keep in mind that the material ordinarily presented in special relativity deals with how to relate events in different reference frames, and doesn't directly address what a single, fixed observer like a camera would see (so, for example, doesn't account for light travel time between an event and a fixed camera). Two effects you'll need to get right are [relativistic aberration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relativistic_Doppler_effect) and the [relativistic Doppler effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relativistic_Doppler_effect).

Comment: Welcome to PSE! Please use MathJax for formulas, you can find a tutorial here: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020